# Javascript get all elements with one class of two

Tags: javascript

i have many divs with class="cat-box" and class="cat-box hidden".

I create a javascript to view all classes with cat-box, but it's counting both of "cat-box" and "cat-box hidden".

How can I count only elements with class cat-box?

My script:

```
function GetMore() {
  var allvis = document.getElementsByClassName('cat-box').length;
  alert(allvis);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `:not` CSS pseudo-class to achieve this:

`document.querySelectorAll('.cat-box:not(.hidden)');`

Answer (score 2):

Use `document.querySelectorAll()` with a selector that excludes the `hidden` elements.

Here's an example...

```js
function GetMore() {
    var allvis = document.querySelectorAll('.cat-box:not(.hidden)').length;
    alert(allvis);
}

document.getElementById("count").addEventListener("click", GetMore);
```

```css
.hidden { color: rgb(200, 200, 200); }
```

```html
<div class="cat-box">cat box</div>
<div class="cat-box hidden">cat box</div>
<div class="cat-box">cat box</div>
<div class="cat-box hidden">cat box</div>
<div class="cat-box">cat box</div>
<button id="count">count</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `querySelector` and `not` in your javascript for that:

```
function GetMore() {
  var allvis = document.querySelectorAll('.cat-box:not(.hidden)').length;
  alert(allvis);
}
```

```js
function GetMore() {
  var allvis = document.querySelectorAll('.cat-box:not(.hidden)').length;
  alert(allvis);
}
GetMore();
```

```html
<div class="cat-box"></div>
<div class="cat-box"></div>
<div class="cat-box hidden"></div>
```

Comment: @undefined agree with that

Answer (score -1):

if you use jquery

```
$("div.cat-box")
```